# Setting default username in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise gem for user management. So, I have a User model.

What I want to be able to do is have a username column in the User model. By default, I want to be able to set the default username for users as 'user'+id where id is unique for every user and a column in User model.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
class AddColsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]

  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string, default: 'user'+id
  end

end
```

Is that possible? Thanks for reading :))

Comment: Doing this as you are trying to is not possible, you can however have triggers on your database if you want to go that route. Usually in Rails this is solved with `before_create` model callbacks

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I realize my approach is not feasible. @Eyeslandic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `before_validation` callback to create a new username. You can expand this a bit to keep retrying in case of failure, but this should hopefully help you get started.

Make sure to add a unique constraint or validation as well!

```rb
before_validation :set_username

private

def set_username
  return if user.blank?

  username = "{user}_#{rand(100)}"
end
```

Another option if you just want a prettier parameter in your url's is to override the `to_param` method in your user model. This will give you a friendly url like "1-my-name", but when parsed to an integer will just be "1" so rails will still find it when doing lookups.

```rb
def to_param
  [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
end
```

Comment: This works. However, in my case I used after_initialize instead of before_validation callback and ||= operator so that whenever there is a new record/user, their username is auto-assigned unless updated. Hope it helps future readers. Thanks @Mike